# Как найти строку между символами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки, re

Есть строка

```
text = "smth text [n=16] smth text"
```

Я создал функцию, которая должна находить значения, указанные в формате:
"[`variable`=`value`]"

```
def get_value(text, var):
    value = re.search(rf'{var}=?[([^]>]+)', text)
    if value:
        value = value.group(1)
        return value
```

Но она не выводит того, что мне нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запустил ваш код с `print(get_value(text, 'n'))` и выдало ошибку `re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 11`

Исправил регулярку и добавил аннотацию типов:

```py
import re


def get_value(text: str, var: str) -> str:
    m = re.search(rf'\[{var}=([^]]+)\]', text)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)


text = "smth text [n=16] smth text"
print(get_value(text, 'n'))
# 16

text = "smth [n=16] text [xyz='123 abc'] smth text"
print(get_value(text, 'xyz'))
# '123 abc'
```